# Create new column by mapping to previous values in dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df,  where I would like to form a new column by taking first letter of column values and mapping values from additional columns within the dataset.

**Data**

```
id  Date    Model   type    status   
aa  Q1 2022 orion   hi01    o_hi    
aa  Q1 2022 orion   hi02    o_hi    
aa  Q1 2022 orion   hello01 o_hello 
aa  Q1 2022 orion   go01    o_go    
bb  Q1 2022 orion   hi01    o_hi    
bb  Q1 2022 orion   hi02    o_hi    
bb  Q1 2022 orion   hi03    o_hi
```

**Desired**

```
id  Date    Model   type    status  NEW
aa  Q1 2022 orion   hi01    o_hi    aa o_hi01 Q1 2022
aa  Q1 2022 orion   hi02    o_hi    aa o_hi02 Q1 2022
aa  Q1 2022 orion   hello01 o_hello aa o_hello01 Q1 2022
aa  Q1 2022 orion   go01    o_go    aa o_go01 Q1 2022
bb  Q1 2022 orion   hi01    o_hi    bb o_hi01 Q1 2022
bb  Q1 2022 vorion  hi02    v_hi    bb v_hi02 Q1 2022
bb  Q1 2022 vorion  hi03    v_hi    bb v_hi03 Q1 2022
```

**Doing**

```
df['NEW'] = df['id'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Model'].astype(str).str[0] + df['type'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Date'].map(str)
```

However, I am troubleshooting on how to incorporate the **first letter of column** values within the newly formed column.

Believe I can incorporate .loc

```
 df['Model'].astype(str).str[0]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.map(str)` because all of your fields are already strings. If needed use `df[column].astype(str)` instead of `df[column].map(str)`.

```
df['New'] = df['id'] + ' ' + df['Model'].str[0] + '_' + df['type'] + ' ' + df['Date']
print(df)

# Output
   id     Date   Model     type   status                   New
0  aa  Q1 2022   orion     hi01     o_hi     aa o_hi01 Q1 2022
1  aa  Q1 2022   orion     hi02     o_hi     aa o_hi02 Q1 2022
2  aa  Q1 2022   orion  hello01  o_hello  aa o_hello01 Q1 2022
3  aa  Q1 2022   orion     go01     o_go     aa o_go01 Q1 2022
4  bb  Q1 2022   orion     hi01     o_hi     bb o_hi01 Q1 2022
5  bb  Q1 2022  vorion     hi02     o_hi     bb v_hi02 Q1 2022
6  bb  Q1 2022  vorion     hi03     o_hi     bb v_hi03 Q1 2022
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['NEW'] = df['id'].map(str) + ' ' + df['status'].astype(str) + df.groupby(['id', 'status']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ' ' + df['Date']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id     Date     type   status                   NEW
0  aa  Q1 2022     hi01     o_hi     aa o_hi01 Q1 2022
1  aa  Q1 2022     hi02     o_hi     aa o_hi02 Q1 2022
2  aa  Q1 2022  hello01  o_hello  aa o_hello01 Q1 2022
3  aa  Q1 2022     go01     o_go     aa o_go01 Q1 2022
4  bb  Q1 2022     hi01     o_hi     bb o_hi01 Q1 2022
5  bb  Q1 2022     hi02     o_hi     bb o_hi02 Q1 2022
6  bb  Q1 2022     hi03     o_hi     bb o_hi03 Q1 2022
```

Comment: Will try- could you explain what the zfill(2) is doing? I understand it it to fill down- but what does the 2 signify? thanks

Comment: `zfill` pads a string with `0`'s until it reaches the specified length. e.g. `'hello'.zfill(10)` returns `00000hello` which is 10 characters long, @Lynn.

Comment: ah ok this didn't work - it is only giving an output of a single column and the order is not as desired @richardec - will troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

```
df['NEW'] = df['id'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Model'].astype(str).str[0] + '_' + df['type'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Date'].map(str)
```